Proving density of the rationals in the reals
Theorem: $a,b \in \mathbb{R}: b>a \implies \exists q \in \mathbb{Q}: a < q < b $
Proof attempt:

We need to show that we can find integers $m,n$ such that $a < \frac mn < b$ or $na < m < nb$.
Lemma: $x-y > 1 \implies \lceil y \rceil < x$
Let $y = z + r$ where $z \in \mathbb{Z}, r \in [0,1)$ then $x-z-r > 1$.
Rounding up is equivalent to adding $1-r$ to $y$, so we get:
$x-y+r-1 > 1+r-1 \implies x - \lceil y \rceil > 1 + r-1 > 0$
$\square$
From this lemma, we just need to show that $nb-na>1$ for some $n$. Since $(b-a)>0$ we know such an $n$ exists from the Archimedean property of the real numbers. Therefore, we can set $m = \lceil na \rceil$.
$\square$

My concern: This seemed too quick but I'm not sure where I skipped a step.

My real analysis textbook took about 20 pages to prove that the rationals (and irrationals) are dense in $~\Bbb{R}.~$  I suggest that you do not try to re-invent the wheel.  Instead, I suggest that you try to find a pertinent real analysis textbook that you are comfortable with.

@user2661923 I have a real analysis book, it proves this in a couple paragraphs. I am trying an alternative approach and want to ensue didn’t oversimplify.
